# Adding tooltips in Gvis timeline through R

Tags: r, timeline, googlevis

I'm looking for a solution in R (if possible) to add a custom tooltip content to a timeline chart built with the googlevis package in R.

Specifically, I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
Content1    StartDate    EndDate    Content2    GroupingVariable    GroupingVariable2
```

I can build the timeline out using the R package using the function gvisTimeline, but I want to know how I can build a custom tooltip for the timeline using the field content2.

The solutions I've seen involve changing the javascript code itself, which I am very unfamiliar with. The reason I am hesistant to do this is that the amount of different content I have would be very timeconsuimg to manually add to the JS code(hundreds of different content) - if I could create the vector in R and use that to populate the tooltip it would be viable.

Further, would it be possible to color the chart based on the a third variable as well?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a possible way to do this. In the `bar label` argument of timechart, if I pass an array of strings such as `barlabel = c("Content1", "Content2.tooltip")` it replaces the tooltip with the custom content. The column must end in the .tooltip for it to work.